# I ran the smart contract and I linked them with the Python file on the virtual box, when running them it gives me error

Tags: python, solidity

ERROR: raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=7545): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f6e001a6400>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

```
import json

import solcx
from solcx import compile_standard
from web3 import Web3

with open("./SimpleStorage.sol","r") as file:
    simple_storage_file= file.read()
'''    print(simple_storage_file) '''
    
compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources":{"Simplestorage.sol":{"content":simple_storage_file}},
        "settings":{
            "outputSelection":{
                "*":{"*":["abi","metadata","evm.bytecode","evm.sourceMap"]}
            }
        },
    },
    solc_version="0.6.0",
    
) 
with open("compiled_code.json","w") as file:
    json.dump(compiled_sol,file)  
     
bytecode = compiled_sol["contracts"]["Simplestorage.sol"]["Simplestorage"]["evm"][
    "bytecode"
]["object"]
#get abi
abi=compiled_sol["contracts"]['Simplestorage.sol']["Simplestorage"]["abi"]

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545"))
chain_id = 5777
my_address = "0xd8001711E3F781D3c762fF2D5e10504CE3033240"
private_key ="0x0ed2c7e46aab218aa085032d315c16d32c0215dd60f0122810378fc636370ff4"

Simplestorage = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode)
nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(my_address)
print(nonce)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't post your Private Key online.

If you wanna test your contract locally, then you will have to have a local test net running.

If you wanna deploy your contract to any network, replace the RPC url with the chain's RPC url.